# How to determine if a tracking marker is inside a mask?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, tracking, masking

How can I determine whether a camera tracking marker is inside or outside a mask that I have created in Blender using Python? For instance, if I create a mask in Blender's masking area for a specific sequence and then want to use the detect feature function in the camera tracking workspace at the start of the sequence. As soon as any of the tracking markers enter the masked area, I want them to be disabled in that frame, so that specific tracking marker do not continue tracking. How can I achieve this functionality? Keep in mind that these masks can be animated and may consist of points connected by a Bezier lines.

[image]